# Copy text with inline hyperlinks as plain text

Tags: clipboard, plaintext

How can I copy selected text from Firefox with inline hyperlinks as plain text?

```
text { hyperlink | http://example.com } more text
```

A partial solution is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/501603/copy-selected-text-with-links), but it's far from perfect.

I have been researching clipboard managers, autoitscript - didn't find a solution yet.
the best solution would be cross-platform.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The question is the same, if you'd like updated/newer/different answer to the existing question please earn [some rep](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) and place some comments and/or [a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on it instead of just duplicating the question.

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox addon [CoLT](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/colt/) adds options to the right-click menu for links, to copy link text, URL etc. in a custom format to clipboard:

> [image: Firefox CoLT right-click menu]

Open the addon options, click *New > Custom Format...* and enter the following:

[image: Firefox Addon CoLT with custom format]

It works for a **link only**, not for links in selected text (but you may email the author this as feature request).

Another solution I can think of is to select the text with links, right-click, *View Selection Source* and copy that. Then use a regular expression in a programmer's text editor or with some scripting language on the copied markup to format everything to your liking (mainly filter out unwanted tags).